# $_GET return nothing

Tags: php, get

I have some problem with an IPN script (paypal notification system).
I have decided to try manualy to find where errors are ...

I tried with an URL like this :

```
pay_validation.php?varone=test&vartwoo=test2

etc...
```

But when i just try an **echo** i get nothing, **echo** code :

```
echo $_GET['varone'];
```

After long search on google i find something about register global and my php configuration but i don't see where : [my php configuration](http://www.urbancenter-store.com/paiement/phpinfo.php)

If someone have an idea ....

**EDIT**

My .htaccess :

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
```

**EDIT**

What var_dump($_SERVER) respond :

```
array(38) { ["PATH"]=> string(28) "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin" ["UNIQUE_ID"]=> string(24) "Te07yAoAPzUAAHkKJpMAAAA4" ["SCRIPT_URL"]=> string(21) "/paiement/phpinfo.php" ["SCRIPT_URI"]=> string(42) "http://urbancenter.fr/paiement/phpinfo.php" ["PHP_VER"]=> string(1) "5" ["REGISTER_GLOBALS"]=> string(1) "0" ["HTTP_REMOTE_IP"]=> string(14) "109.208.33.238" ["HTTP_HOST"]=> string(14) "urbancenter.fr" ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=> string(83) "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1" ["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=> string(63) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" ["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=> string(35) "fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3" ["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=> string(13) "gzip, deflate" ["HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET"]=> string(30) "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7" ["HTTP_KEEP_ALIVE"]=> string(3) "115" ["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=> string(10) "keep-alive" ["HTTP_REFERER"]=> string(65) "http://www.urbancenter-store.com/paiement/phpinfo.php?varone=test" ["HTTP_COOKIE"]=> string(187) "__utma=11976432.740870953.1307016203.1307290250.1307386638.3; __utmz=11976432.1307290250.2.2.utmcsr=urbancenter-store.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/; mediaplan=R3757121280" ["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=> string(0) "" ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=> string(18) "Apache/2.2.X (OVH)" ["SERVER_NAME"]=> string(14) "urbancenter.fr" ["SERVER_ADDR"]=> string(13) "178.33.103.17" ["SERVER_PORT"]=> string(2) "80" ["REMOTE_ADDR"]=> string(14) "109.208.33.238" ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(23) "/homez.370/urbancen/www" ["SERVER_ADMIN"]=> string(25) "postmaster@urbancenter.fr" ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=> string(44) "/homez.370/urbancen/www/paiement/phpinfo.php" ["REMOTE_PORT"]=> string(5) "52210" ["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=> string(7) "CGI/1.1" ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=> string(8) "HTTP/1.1" ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=> string(3) "GET" ["QUERY_STRING"]=> string(0) "" ["REQUEST_URI"]=> string(21) "/paiement/phpinfo.php" ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=> string(21) "/paiement/phpinfo.php" ["UID"]=> string(5) "11764" ["PHP_SELF"]=> string(21) "/paiement/phpinfo.php" ["REQUEST_TIME"]=> int(1307392968) ["argv"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "phpinfo.php" } ["argc"]=> int(1) }
```

Comment: Are you using a framework such as CodeIgniter that can destroy the `$_GET` variable?

Comment: Do you use any kind of rewrite, or such?

Comment: register globals is not what you need. And is deprecated

Comment: @zim32: it has nothing to do with this

Comment: didn't use any rewrite i put my htaccess

Comment: as I said, try my answer

Comment: @genesis print_R($_GET) but i already try this and it return an empty array or you talk of another answer ?

Comment: as I said, give me link to that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved ....
The problem was due of a 301 redirect make by a stupid ....

When i try the same thing on [this adress](http://www.urbancenter.fr/paiement/phpinfo.php?varone=test) it work fine

Thank to all -)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a framework such as CodeIgniter that can destroy the `$_GET` variable?

Comment: I didn't use any framework, it's an old website on a recent hoster ^^

Comment: quite odd: what does `var_dump($_GET);` and `var_dump($_REQUEST);` produce.

Comment: second give : array(3) { ["__utma"]=> string(53) "11976432.740870953.1307016203.1307290250.1307386638.3" ["__utmz"]=> string(95) "11976432.1307290250.2.2.utmcsr=urbancenter-store.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/" ["mediaplan"]=> string(11) "R3757121280" }

Comment: Very odd: it only has cookies in it, no request parameters. I think either your host is doing something very weird or you have some code somewhere that is causing other problems: what does `var_dump($_SERVER);` say?

Comment: Specifically what does `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` say?

Comment: echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] produce : string(21) "/paiement/phpinfo.php"

Comment: var_dump($_SERVER) say : watch in my answer respond is too long

Comment: Well, if `REQUEST_URI` has no query parameters then that would explain why $_GET is empty: you are CLEARLY passing no request parameters in. Pass in some request parameters and see what `var_dump($_GET);` gives you.

Comment: i tried this for test what you want : http://www.urbancenter-store.com/paiement/phpinfo.php?varone=test

Comment: Yeah, your host has problems: see that **["QUERY_STRING"]=> string(0) ""** is blank?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using rewrites? Could you try `var_dump($_GET['varone']);` ?

If that gives `NULL` the `$_GET['varone']` probably isn't set.

Could you also `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` ?

Answer (score 0):

create new file, and put there

```
<?php
print_R($_GET);
?>
```

give me link to that file then, if you can ...

Comment: give me an empty array : Array()

Comment: put here content of your .htaccess please

Comment: SetEnv PHP_VER 5
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0

Comment: But i have already try to comment the content of my .htaccess

Comment: yes, I saw it, but it has no Rewrites. Do what does my answer say

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your host is trying to force the use of the `filter` extensions? Unlikely, but give it a try:

```
 echo filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'varone');
```

Comment: Warning: filter_input() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given in /homez.370/urbancen/www/paiement/phpinfo.php on line 3

Comment: Be sure you entered `INPUT_GET` as a constant, not quoted as a string. Else it sounds like you have a really odd server. Do you have access to another system you can test on?